# Understanding Jenkinsfile's steps for Docker agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkinsfile with the following steps:

```
stage('build') {
      agent {
           docker {
               image 'maven:3-alpine'
               args '-v /ec2-user/.m2:/root/.m2'
           }
      }
      steps {
        git(url: 'https://github.com/user/project.git', branch: 'master')
        sh 'cp /home/application-prod.properties src/main/resources'
        sh 'mvn clean install'
      }
    }
```

According to docs, Jenkins should **Execute the steps in this stage in a newly created container using this image.**

If that is true, then why the second step's **sh** command is executed successfully? How can it access the file on the Jenkins host?

To me, it looks like the commands are executed on the Jenkins host. Then why **mvn clean install** works fine? Jenkins host doesn't have Maven installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is the usual case that you want to access the contents of your workspace, Jenkins automatically mounts it as a volume into the container. Otherwise, in probably 99% of all jobs, one would have to specify that the checked out repo should be mounted into the container.

You should be able to see the `-v` parameters in the output of the build when it issues the `docker run` command.

Comment: Thank you, I see it in the logs. But **/home** directory with the props file is not inside the mapped workspace directory and is not mapped to the container by default. How the container is accessing it?

Comment: I see, what's the build output?

Comment: The build successfully runs and I get a valid jar artifact with the intended **application-prod.properties** inside /target directory in Jenkins workspace.
Also, I noticed that in the logs the Jenkins workspace directory is mapped not with the **-v** flag, but with **-w** (as a workdir), but I still can't get it how the /home dir is accessed.

Comment: Probably, I got it. My Jenkins host is also running in the container. And when Maven container is run, there is also **--volumes-from** option (along with the **-w**) which maps all Jenkins' container volumes into the Maven container.
Thank you for your help!